# php pthreads: 'PHP Fatal error' , 'Fatal error' in CLI

Tags: php, pthreads

I ran all example of `https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/seven/examples` in CLI.
After executing each one, I get `PHP Fatal error` and `Fatal error` ,in addition to expected result.
For example in this case `https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/seven/examples/ClosureFuture.php` I'll get:

```
object(Volatile)#6 (2) { 
[0]=> 
    string(5) "Hello" 
[1]=> 
    string(5) "World" 
} 
array(2) { 
[0]=> 
    string(5) "Hello" 
[1]=> 
    string(5) "World" 
}
```

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class Future, because the name is already in use in /var/www/test/index1.php on line 42
>
> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Future, because the name is already in use in /var/www/test/index1.php on line 42

In all example error occured when extended class closed.

Do you know the reason of these errors and how to correct them?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
class Future extends Thread {
    private function __construct(Closure $closure, array $args = []) {
        $this->closure = $closure;
        $this->args    = $args; 
    }
    public function run() {
        $this->synchronized(function() {
            $this->result = 
                ($this->closure)(...$this->args);
            $this->notify();
        });
    }
    public function getResult() {
        return $this->synchronized(function(){
            while (!$this->result)
                $this->wait();
            return $this->result;
        });
    }
    
    public static function of(Closure $closure, array $args = []) {
        $future = 
            new self($closure, $args);
        $future->start();
        return $future;
    }
    
    protected $owner;
    protected $closure;
    protected $args;
    protected $result;
}//line 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your server installed PHP version. According to doc, its supporting from (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0).

Comment: Thanks for reply, my current php version is 5.5.8 and also I tested it on versions 7.0.0RC4, 7.0.0RC3, 7.0.0RC2.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have found a bug, or some bugs in pthreads, please report them on github.

Please include in the report as much information as possible "Fatal Error" is not very useful.

PHP7 and pthreads v3 are pre-release quality, the quoted example ClosureFuture was just updated in the last commit, along with a minor change.